# Copy controls from one form to another

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have many labels and text boxes on a form.  They're all lined up great and named.  Is it safe for me to copy all these controls to another form and rename them?  I want to be able to preserve their sizes and locations on the new form which is why I want to use the originals.  I do not have any code yet in the original text boxes so that is not important.  Thanks

Comment: yes it is safe. however, using usercontrols is usually a better way to use controls multiple times.

Comment: No worries. I also added an answer with the related link to help you learn about user controls. I assume that you're using winforms. Is that right? Or are you using WPF?

Comment: Yes, I'm using winforms.  Thanks for the link....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** it is safe.

However, using [usercontrols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) is usually a better way to use controls multiple times (You should not break the DRY rule).